# How to conditional order results in mySql?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have this scenario:
A user enter my application and push a button to look for a pair on a game. When he click the button, I do a insert in a table, whit his ID, his level, his countryID and a datetime whith NOW().
Then, I need to look in this table, trying to find a pair to play with him.
my problem is, i need to order the results based on the user level.

So, imagine my table have this rows:

```
  |ID |userID|userLv|    date_add        | country_ID |
  ----------------------------------------------------
  | 1 | 1    |3     |2016-06-24 12:09:06 | 5          |
  | 2 | 2    |2     |2016-06-24 04:26:24 | 8          |
  | 3 | 3    |2     |2016-06-24 11:38:54 | 1          |
  | 4 | 4    |1     |2016-06-24 11:10:06 | 9          |
  | 5 | 5    |2     |2016-06-24 11:35:49 | 6          |
  | 6 | 6    |1     |2016-06-24 20:09:13 | 10         |
```

If a user with level 1 click the button, he needs to be matched with another user of level 1, odered by date_add ASC. But if there are no users of level 1 available, he will be paired with a user of level 2, again order by date_add ASC. if there are no level 2 users available, the he will be paired with a user of level 3.

Basically, i need a script that can return the rows ordered first by the userLv = x, then the other levels. How to do this with only one request to the database? Does this even make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simple use a correlated query with `LIMIT` to get the second user id :

```
SELECT t.*,
       (SELECT s.userID FROM YourTable s
        WHERE s.userLv >= t.userLv
        ORDER BY s.userLv 
        LIMIT 1) as user2_id
FROM YourTable t
WHERE t.userID = <YourParamOrWhatEver>
```

Comment: Perfect! I just edited so the query returned the next ID, not the ID of the one who is searching:  
 `SELECT t.*,
       (SELECT s.userID FROM table s
        WHERE s.level >= t.level AND s.userID <> 1
        ORDER BY s.level, s.date_add
        LIMIT 1) as user2_id
FROM table t
where t.userID = 1`

Answer (score 0):

You can use your sql commands 1 at a time. Check if a same level query returns something and repeat it for some seconds. Then if you had no result, check the next sql statement for the same time and so on.

Comment: Yeah, i've thinked of that too. But this database have lots of rows, and i was trying to do this with a single command.